# Why I can't add an ImageView in the tabbed page?

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

so I just recently started to develop Android applications via Xamarin and I am struggling a LOT.
I created my application like this(in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition):
**New Project -> Visual C# -> Android -> Android App(Xamarin) -> Tabbed App(Android version 5.0).**

Then I drag **ImageView** anywhere on the screen.I try to run it and it crashes with the exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

**What I tried:**
1) doing this in new Visual studio version - 2019.
2) Putting this in a blank app - it does work, but I need the tabbed page functionality for my app, so that's not an option.

Any tips & tricks are appreciated.Here are the images to visualize it.
[Code line where it crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5wzX.png)
[This is how it looks from the designer perspective.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1pG9.png)
[Error from designer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihtYK.png)

MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App10
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        TextView textMessage;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Error on this line.
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            textMessage = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message);
            BottomNavigationView navigation = FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
            navigation.SetOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
        public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.navigation_home:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_home);
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_dashboard:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_dashboard);
                    return true;
                case Resource.Id.navigation_notifications:
                    textMessage.SetText(Resource.String.title_notifications);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please do NOT post code and errors as images

Comment: What is the target framework you are using? It maybe the version (miss-match) of appcompat and support library versions...

Comment: Code as Images is not the best as we can't copy/paste it to help work out your issue or in the case of the last image "Error from designer window" see the end of the error.

Comment: I added the source code from one of the images.I can't copy/paste the exception error from designer window.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Where I can find the versions?

Comment: Can you show the `Resource.Layout.activity_main` view? You sure it's not supposed to be `Resource.Layout.Main`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you can see the view in the 2nd image.Name of the view is made by the visual studio, I didn't change anything, it's a clean project.

Comment: `InflateException` doesn't tell you much; just that _something_ went wrong during inflation. You'll need to look further on in the stack trace for the root `Exception`.

Comment: I found something, but that doesn't tell me much: https://imgur.com/a/7iwCDUG , https://imgur.com/a/WNktGfL  , any tips?

Comment: @TheFunnySmell From new created xamarin android project,if you not changed anything .Not  draging `ImageView` to  `activity_main.axml` ,have a try to drag to `content_main.axml`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT there is no such file as "content_main.axml" or are you saying that I need to rename the activity_main.axml ?

Comment: @TheFunnySmell No, because I do not know the file in your project. `content_main.axml` appear in my new create xamarin android project.Could you share your new create project, I will check it.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Here you go: download link for the .zip: https://ufile.io/z1g26z0u

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT This is not a Xamarin.Forms project by  the way, this is what it is: https://imgur.com/a/QiXElNK

Comment: @TheFunnySmell Thanks for sharing.I know it's a xamarin android project.I will check it. :)

Comment: @TheFunnySmell I have checked it.The same error ,the reason is you use the wrong way to add view to Tabbed page.I will update answer.

Comment: @TheFunnySmell This should be a bug of vs, not your problem. Which version of your VS  *.^

Comment: MIcrosoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I drag ImageView anywhere on the screen.I try to run it and it crashes with the exception:

After testing , I found that this is not your problem, this should be a bug for VS.

**Solution:**

After modify **axml** file, you need to clean project, then rebuild it. This error will not happen.

`Clean Solution -> Build Solution` can solve it.

Comment: Thank you sir, that solved my problem, but the VS folks should fix it ASAP.Maybe address it in the github repo page?

Comment: @TheFunnySmell Yeah, you can adress it in the github.And remember to share github link here : )